# AppCompatActivity crashing the application

Tags: java, android-studio, crash

I'm using this Adapter to set some variables in another XML Layout and also to change the from the fragment Home to DescDenuncia in this process I'm passing some values through it, and every time that I click in RLAYOUT my application crashes. Other important thing to say is that the problem ins't in the "model.getEmpresa" variables seems like the real problem is the transaction screem itself.

```
package com.example.safe;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;

//Vinculando o reclycler view ao firestore
public class Adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Modelo, Adapter.myviewholder> {


    public Adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Modelo> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    //Sobrescrevendo o método
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull final Modelo model) {
        //Associando os itens do atalho ocorrências
        holder.IDText.setText(model.getID());
        holder.tipoText.setText(model.getTipo());
        Glide.with(holder.img1.getContext()).load(model.getImg()).into(holder.img1);

        ///////////////////////////////////////THE PROBLEM IS HERE///////////////////////////////////////////
        holder.RLAYOUT.setOnClickListener(new View. OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new Perfil(
                        model.getEmpresa(),
                        model.getArea(),
                        model.getSetor(),
                        model.getTipo(),
                        model.getRisco(),
                        model.getImg(),
                        model.getData(),
                        model.getPrazo(),
                        model.getDesc(),
                        model.getResolucao(),
                        model.getID()
                        )).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.modelo_atalho_ocorrencias, parent, false);
        return new myviewholder(view);

    }

    //Coneção do reclycler view com essa classe
    public class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //Variáveis do modelo atalho
        TextView tipoText, IDText;
        RelativeLayout RLAYOUT;
        ImageView img1;

        //Associando os objetos ao modelo atalho
        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            tipoText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTipo);
            img1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            IDText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtModeloID);
            RLAYOUT = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RLlayout);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The comment in your code is shouting where the problem is but we have no idea why its crashing nor what is the exception being thrown..

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74189022/how-to-get-the-context-of-a-item-in-reclycler-view/74189061#74189061